# How to update last record in SQL Server using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I tried to update last record in my SQL Server database table but it has no change I don't know what is the wrong can any one help me?

This is my code

```
conn.Open();
SqlCommand sq = new SqlCommand("update Hodor_data set leaving_time = ('" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "') where mil_no = '" +textBox1.Text+ "' and times = (select max(times) from Hodor_data ", conn);
sq.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

and my database is

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kKaR.jpg]

Comment: You have missing ")" in here;  `(select max(times) from Hodor_data `

Comment: Side note: You might want to research "sql injection".

Comment: thax berkay but it update all (times) every time i make this process

Comment: And storing a date/time in a varchar field is a basic error

Comment: i mean not only the max (times) but also all times

Comment: I would recommend moving the code for your update / select into a stored procedure and test it out on the server by executing only the SELECT statement, once you get that working then apply the UPDATE Select...

Comment: thx guys it worked ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but hopefully does what you want:

```
// You might want to consider making your SQL type a DateTime of 
// some sort to prevent invalid DateTime VARCHAR's from being 
// stored in your leaving_time and arrival_time columns.
var leavingTime = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();

// Presumably you've already done validation to make sure
// textBox1.Text contains a valid Int32 value.
var milNo = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

// You can put the SQL out here on a multi-line string literal
// to make it more readable.  Also notice how it uses parameters
// instead of string concatenation.
var sql = @"
UPDATE Hodor_data 
SET leaving_time = @LeavingTime
WHERE 
    mil_no = @MilNo AND 
    times = 
    (
        SELECT MAX(times) 
        FROM Hodor_data
    )
";

conn.Open();
SqlCommand sq = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
sq.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LeavingTime", leavingTime);
sq.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MilNo", milNo);
sq.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Also, consider using a `using` to manage closing your `SqlConnection`'s unless you have need to reuse the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
string sql = "update Hodor_data set leaving_time = '"+dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString()+"' where mil_no = "+textBox1.Text+" and times = (select max(times) from Hodor_data)";

SqlCommand sq = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
```

If multiple records have the times value, multiple record will be updated.